# SafeCracker problems... Playa Field inside a Matrix

Tags: matrix, safecracker, playa, zoo-visitor

I'm having trouble getting Safecracker to create the rows on a Matrix field. I've managed to get this to work IF the field is a 'Text Input' field.

But when the field is a Playa field, it doesn't create the row.

My code is (I'm pulling the data from a channel:entries loop):

```
{!-- Create New Row --}
<input type="hidden" name="member_courses[row_order][]" value="row_new_{exp:mx_calc expression="{count}-1"}">

{!-- Course ID / Name --}
<input type="hidden" name="member_courses[row_new_{exp:mx_calc expression="{count}-1"}][col_id_20]" value="[{entry_id}] [{url_title}] {title}">
```

I found that if you add this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="member_courses[selections][]" value="{entry_id}">
```

It should work, but it doesn't.

How can I get Safecracker to create an entry, that creates rows in a Matrix (But also creates the relationship)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Playa input name to this:

```
field_name[row_new_X][col_id_Y][selections][]
```

And the value should only be the entry ID.

So in your case I guess that would be:

```
<input type="hidden"
       name="member_courses[row_new_{exp:mx_calc expression="{count}-1"}][col_id_20][selections][]"
       value="{entry_id}">
```

Comment: Fantastic! That worked. I just couldn't get my head around it.